# Can someone help me with this Minecraft command?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

```
/scoreboard players tag @a flowerpot {SelectedItem:[{id:"minecraft:flower_pot",tag:{display:{Lore:["Işınlayan Saksı"}]}}}]
```

I writing this command but not working.
What is the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The syntax of `/scoreboard players tag` is:

```
/scoreboard players tag <player> <add|remove|list> <tagName> [dataTag]
```

You are missing `add` before `flowerpot`.

---

`SelectedItem` should be a compound tag (curly brackets) rather than a list (square brackets).

There's also some other issues with your closing brackets, such as trying to close `Lore:[` with `}` rather than `]`.

---

The fixed command should be:

```
/scoreboard players tag @a add flowerpot {SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:flower_pot",tag:{display:{Lore:["Işınlayan Saksı"]}}}}
```

Comment: Hmm I understand